# How to put a checkbox in group, but in other column in ag-grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular, ag-grid-react

Trying to put checkbox for all rows in Athlete column, I don't need  checkbox on group columns

And also want to remove toggling feature from group..should not allow user to collpase.

Please assist
[code link](https://plnkr.co/edit/lnF09XtK3eDo1a5v) `code`

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/lnF09XtK3eDo1a5v

Comment: I can not see any checkboxes in the above plunker example.

Comment: I updated it later and got the solution

Comment: I saw the example, thats the right solution. good job

Answer (score 2):

Got the solution updated plunker accordingly

plnkr.co/edit/lnF09XtK3eDo1a5v